# Physical modification of RS422 to ensure one-way dataflow

Tags: rs422

Is it possible to physically modify an RS422 connection such as by removing Pins from the terminals or physically cutting the wires so there is zero possibility for return data flow. I have one device (Device A) that needs to ONLY transmit data to one other device (Device B) and need to ensure there is zero possibility for Device B to send anything to Device A. I only have control over the cable itself.

Comment: On RS422 you have one wire pair for each direction, so, yes, you can disconnect one pair to suppress a direction.

Comment: I don't understand - are you asking if you can remove signals from a connector? Yes you can... Are you actually asking about RS-485 and not RS-422?

Answer (score 3):

RS-422 pairs are unidirectional, so there will always be one active transmitter on a pair and a transmit pair can't receice data.

If your device has both receive and transmit pair, then you can disconnect the pair you don't want.

Comment: Thanks Jens. That's what I thought.